# Download Program files in Run time iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am doing an R&D to find a way to keep program files in cloud and download it in run time when required. It is similar to downloading next level package for Games in iOS app. Our app has too many modules which is not required for all the users so I wish I could keep source files (.h .m & .swift) in cloud and download it in run time when user gets into that modules. I am aware that we can tranfer images/videos/files from cloud storage to app. But is it possible to download source files and compile it in run time? Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would surely violate Apple's App Store guidelines, even if it was technically possible.

Comment: To add, there's no compiler in iOS devices.

Comment: Specifically https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements 2.5.2